# grails: Behaviour of list.contains in code vs integration test

Tags: list, grails, integration-testing

Imagine there is a form to do a bulk update for a group of logins and their statuses; the logic used is about having a hidden field which keeps track of all possible ids and a group of… e.g. radio btns. later thru a service, activating whatever checked ids in our list and deactivating rest:

```
def enabledLogins = toList(params.enabledLogins)
def allLoginIds = params.allLoginIds.toString().split(',')
loginService.updateLoginStatus(allLoginIds,enabledLogins)
```

here is the definition for the service

```
def updateLoginStatus(String[] allLoginIds, List<Long> enabledLoginIds) {
    for (item in allLoginIds) {
        def login = Login.get(item.toLong())
        if (login) {
            login.enabled = enabledLoginIds.contains(item.toLong()) ? true : false
            login.save()
            if (login.hasErrors()) {
                login.errors.each { log.error(it) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the integration test:

```
def testUpdateLoginStatus() {
    def id1 = createLogin().id
    def id2 = createLogin().id

    String[] allLoginIds = [id1 as String, id2 as String]
    List<Long> enabledLoginIds = [id1]

    loginService.updateLoginStatus(allLoginIds, enabledLoginIds)

    def login1 = Login.get(id1)
    def login2 = Login.get(id2)
    assertTrue login1.enabled
    assertFalse login2.enabled
}
Login createLogin() {
    def now = System.currentTimeMillis()

    def email = "int-test-" + now + "@somewhere.com"
    def password = "Pwd" + now + "pwD"

    def login = new Login(username: email, password: password, firstName: "Integration", lastName: "Test")
    login.save(flush: true)
    assertNotNull login.id

    return login
}
```

**now here is the problem:**
The code above just passes integration test but not working in practice unless I take the ***toLong*** out of the

```
enabledLoginIds.contains(item.toLong())
```

which in that case integration test fails...
so the type somewhere somehow, is wrong... but I cannot see it
thanks
Ps: grails 1.3.7

Comment: Is there a stacktrace output or does it just fail silently?

Comment: Seems odd that it works in `def login = Login.get(item.toLong())`. 
This might be trivial for this sample use case, but its best practice to check with `isLong()` before invoking `toLong()`

Comment: I'd imagine that you're not setting the id manually in createLogin() but can you try: List<Long> enabledLoginIds = [id1 as Long]

Comment: @Jarred: right, id is coming from another function(updated above) and not manually inserted, tried your suggestion, integration still fails :(

Comment: @gotomanners: applied conditional call for toLong in service, integration still fails :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All parameters come across as Strings so the code in your Controller is:

```
def enabledLogins = toList(params.enabledLogins)
```

Which is creating a list of Strings.  This is why if you take out the .toLong() when you're running the app it works.  Because then it is doing:

```
["1", "2"].contains("1")
```

Instead of your current implementation with the .toLong which would result in:

```
["1", "2"].contains(1)
```

There are a couple of things that I see here:

1) Remember that generics are compile time only (so basically worthless in groovy).  So even though you have a parameter of `(... , List<Long> enabledLoginIds)` in your method signature.  At runtime there is no guarantee that it will be a List of Longs.

2) I usually integration test through the controller.  This give you a little better end to end test and helps to avoid problems like this.  Where it passes the test, but doesn't work in production so then you think there's something wrong with the test.